# MOCK testing issue using Mockito

Tags: database, unit-testing, object, mockito

I am facing issue after creating the mock in the line below:

```
Query<? extends   Model>q=h.createQuery(query).setFetchSize(100).fetchForward().map(new xyxMapper());
```

It is failing while calling map, giving null.
What's going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Without seeing your setup code, it's going to be very hard for us to diagnose what you're doing wrong (or not doing at all). It's likely a matter of stubbing `fetchForward()` to return itself, or setting up the mock with RETURNS_SELF as the default answer, but we really need more information before a definitive solution is clear. Cheers!

Comment: We can solve this by mocking the handle obejct